# Creating *.mat file from Python without using dictionary

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, scipy, mat-file

I have few lists which i want to save it to a `*.mat file`. But according to `scipy.io.savemat` command documentation i Need to create a dictionary with the lists and then use the command to save it to a `*.mat file`.

If i save it according to the way mentioned in the docs the mat file will have structure with variables as the Arrays which i used in the dictionary. Now i have a Problem here, **I have another program (which is not editable) will use the mat files** and load them to plot some Graphs from the data. The program cannot process the structure because it is written in a way where if it loads a mat files and then it will directly process the Arrays in it.

So is there a way to save the `mat file` without using `dictionaries`? Please see the Image for more understanding[image: *.mat file with struct]

[image: *.mat file without struct]

Thanks

This is the sample algorithm i used to save my `*.mat file`

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
import scipy.io as sio

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[234,5445,778] #can be 1000 lists

data={}

data['x']=x
data['y']=y
sio.savemat('test.mat',{'interpolated_data':data})
```

Comment: Don't you simply need a dictionary where keys (which will be names after loaded in MATLAB) corresponds with names expected in this non-editable program?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I did not understand what you mean exactly. Can you explain it a bit more

Comment: can you add an example of the code that calls `scipy.io.savemat`? it seems like you are abusing this function...

Comment: @Shai I will add the code

Comment: @Shai I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
scipy.io.savemat('interpolated_data_max_compare.mat', 
                 {'NA1_X_order10_ACCE_ms2': np.zeros((3000,1)),
                  'NA1_X_order10_DISP_mm': np.ones((3000,1))})
```

Should work fine...

According to the code you added in your question, instead of `sio.savemat('...', {'interpolated_data':data})`, just save

```
sio.savemat('...', data)
```

and you should be fine: `data` is already a dictionary you don't need to add an extra level with `{'interpolated_data': data}` when saving.

Comment: If i have many lists how you would you suggest me to write the command?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Writing primitives directly

```
import scipy.io.matlab as ml

f=open("something.mat","wb")
mw=ml.mio5.MatFile5Writer(f)
mw.put_variables({"testVar":22})
```

Comment: shouldn't `f` be open for write (and binary?). what is `s`? should it be `f`?

Comment: can you add a link do a documentation of `ml.mio5`? is it possible it's simply the backend of `scipy.io.savemat`?

Comment: Yes and yes, it's the backend, `scipy.io.matlab.mio5` referenced at the end of `savemat` help.